# How I can return my result as 0.1f as a floating point number

Tags: java, android, int

I need to get the result as 0.2f when I do the following calculation.
But I am getting 0.2 as my answer.Please guide me where I am wrong.

```
int progressChanged = 2;
float floatParam = (float)progressChanged / 10;
```

Answer is=0.2
But my expectation is 0.2f

Comment: You have to print it appending the `f` then. A float value cannot have characters in them.

Comment: Why should it print, or however you get the value, 0.2f? You don´t write 0.2f on a paper either. In the end it´s still a number and not a word.

Comment: convert into string then convert back to float

Comment: I want to pass the float value (0.2f ) in some function..

Comment: Looks like you want to pass String to next method, you can write a simple suffix method and achieve this.

Comment: Simply said, 0.2**f** is not a number. It's a String. In **code** you can use the f to represent floats. But only in **code**.

Comment: In java 0.2 will be double and 0.2f will be float

Comment: if you think 0.2 could be double than cast it to float

Comment: **0.2 is 0.2**. No matter if you DESCRIBE it as double or as float.

Answer (score 1):

```
float floatValue = (float)progressChanged / 10;

String floatParam = floatValue + "f";
```

Create a `String` and append `f` to it and then use your function definition this way.

```
public void myFunction(String value)
{
   System.out.println(value");
}
```

---

*In java 0.2 will be double and 0.2f will be float*

`0.2` is also a float, change your method signature to float, It will be a float, you don't need a `f`.

```
public void myFunction(float value)
    {
       System.out.println(value);
    }
```

Comment: In java 0.2 will be double and 0.2f will be float I am saying that way

Comment: Oh so that's yours problem. 0.2 is float too. Change your method signature.

Answer (score 0):

```
float floatParam = (float)progressChanged / 10;
```

convert the `floatParam` to `string` then upend the character `f` to `string`

Answer (score 0):

I have to pass object of this (Float) class in my method 
 and I have used below code and its accepting the params.

Float floatParam = Float.valueOf(progressChanged / 10.0f);